# Swift: Declaring (and initialising) a variable of type function

Tags: swift, function, reference

I'd like to declare a variable of type `(Int)->String`, to be used later in the code. How to do this?

This code:

```
var myfunc: (Int)->String = nil
```

gives an error.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable must be optional type to accept `nil`. Try:

```
var myfunc: ((Int) -> String)?
```

Note: You don't need `= nil` here, it's redundant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `nil` is still needed. Otherwise, the variable is not initialized

Comment: Oh, I thought it assumes the initial value to be `nil`. Thanks for correcting me. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: Actually, just tried it, and I was wrong - it's works without assignment to `nil`

Comment: Lol, So I was right? I did try too, since you seemed sure I was going through other SO post regarding the same.

Comment: Please consider that in terms of Swift `nil` is not a value, so `nil` as *initial value* is a contradiction in terms.